# What changes should i make in my wsdl file to directly consume in SAP ABAP Proxy?

Tags: soap, wsdl, abap

I have created a soap service using jax-ws in java.I want to consume my WSDL in SAP directly using ABAP proxy. How can i make my WSDL compatible for SAP?

I tried including Max and Min occurrence in my WSDL file. It is working when i test with soap ui. But still getting error in SAP like

> SOAP Fault Code:3 One or More Soap header block not understood.

I have searched for this error but couldn't find anything useful.

This is WSDL file which is generated from XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://example.com/soap" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/soap" targetNamespace="http://example.com/soap">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/soap">

    <xs:element name="getOrderRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="purchaseOrderNumber" type="xs:long"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="vCode" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="vName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Location" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lineItem" type="tns:lineItem"                                                                                            
maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="lineItem">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Order_No" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="Material" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="UOM" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="Tax" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:decimal"/>
            
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="getOrderResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getOrderRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getOrderRequest" name="getOrderRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getOrderResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getOrderResponse" name="getOrderResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="OrderService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getOrder">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getOrderRequest" name="getOrderRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getOrderResponse" name="getOrderResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="OrderServiceSoap11" type="tns:OrderService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getOrder">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="getOrderRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getOrderResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="OrderServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:OrderServiceSoap11" name="OrderServiceSoap11">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8089/Soap/app/OrderService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I want to know whether my WSDL file is correct?

Comment: ABAP proxies may be generated from any WSDL file, with a few restrictions described in note [944029 - XML schema supported by ABAP proxy generation](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/944029/E). You may obtain more information by running the program RSSIDL_DESERIALIZE_DEMO (cf note [2316450 - Error SRT Framework exception: Error in WSDL parsing: Incorrect value: Entity ... '>' or '/>' expected](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2316450/E)). You have to adjust the WSDL file manually to get around those restrictions.

Comment: Can you please explain the error code soap fault3:One or More Soap header block not understood?

Comment: An error message is meaningless if you don't explain where it comes from. Anyway, I get clear error messages when I attempt creating the proxy: `Unknown namespace //example.com/soap`. If I look at the namespaces you used, I see that the WSDL URL does not start with "http://..." as classically done. Moreover, is `//` a valid prefix in URLs? Shouldn't you try with classic URLs?

Comment: no no that i know it should be http:// i removed it because stack overflow was giving error like spam question.

Comment: I have edited your question accordingly (to include the missing `http://`; look at the edit revision to understand what your error was)

Comment: Please update your question to explain how to reproduce (SE80, etc.), because it's unclear (I get a different error than yours).

Comment: actually my proxy is successfully generated.when i run my code then i am getting error.maybe there is some communication error because i checked my configuration and its correct.

Comment: Please provide the ABAP code that you use to call the proxy, to conform [stackoverflow MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wsdl policy and service elements are missing. You said that you are getting **SOAP header understood** error. SOAP header generally used for authentication and generally old SAP version not support authentication in header segment. Change your java code and try with basic authentication.

Comment: How can i add basic authentication? Please can you reference any document or example? I am using spring-ws.

Comment: This is different new question. Check this: https://codenotfound.com/spring-ws-basic-authentication-example.html